# Google Region Biasing in Jquery Scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I can't seem to get this right at the moment, Google talks about region basing here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes

It uses the following parameter:

```
region:
```

This is the code im working with: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/19/

My question is how do I pass my variable "ctryiso" to this parameter in my script? When I try, nothing changes, so when ctryiso is set to US and I type in London it still geocodes London, England. I've heard it may be a bit unreliable but still I don't think my implementation is correct.

Comment: your fiddle isin't opening

Comment: Just FYI: I'm not able to access https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/19/ (HTTPS) - but am able to access http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/19/ (HTTP)

Comment: I get the coordinates for London, England, if I just type in "London". But all suggestions are for US locations.

Comment: Fixed my jsfiddle, thanks for that.

Comment: I want to make it so it is bias, so it shouldnt return London England if I put my bias as the US

Comment: isn't using componentRestrictions already solved the problem? from what i see in your fiddle, after setting the ctryiso i and the autocomplete restricts to the country.

Comment: It's not about the autocomplete its about the value in th field

Comment: [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277068/google-geocode-region-works-only-in-certain-cases/27278824#27278824) is a similar problem with some more detailed solutions and examples that may help people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally where you have:

```
geocoder.geocode({
    address: query
}
```

You should pass `region` just like that (as you already mentioned):

```
geocoder.geocode({
    address: query,
    region: SOME_VARIABLE_WITH_REGION_CODE
}
```

And it should work, although... it seems it isn't and more people are having the same problem.

The (ugly) solution is to add it to address, like this:

```
geocoder.geocode({
    address: query + ', ' + SOME_VARIABLE_WITH_REGION_CODE
}
```

I've just tested it and it works, but as i said - it's not the "nice" neither correct way to do it - it's just workaround.

As we can see here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=th-TH&csw=1#GeocoderRequest

You can pass `address`, `bounds`, `location` and `region`. Since region doesn't seems to be working, i'd try to use `bounds` by first getting coordinates for desired region:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=th-TH&csw=1#LatLngBounds

Comment: The hack of adding the region code to your address query may usually work, but a better way to restrict to a country (vs bias) is to use  GeocoderComponentRestrictions (see my answer here for details).

Answer (score 0):

- You can try adding the region parameter as a query string when you
  load google map APIs, although by default it should be US

  ```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&region=US
  ```
- You can also append ",USA" to the address you pass to the geocoder - 
  that works really well but it is ugly.
- You could also return all the results and parse them and display only
  ones that are in the country of interest. In most    cases you will
  have    to do that anyhow as there are multiple    locations with the
  same name in most    countries .... This is the    preferred method
  as if someone types in London, USA you will get    London, KY and
  London,OH and the user/you still needs to decide which    one it is
  they want...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a different answer, you can include the `region` in your geocode request to bias (not restrict) the result.

However, in this particular case, London in the UK is still considered a better result than London in the US.  Therefore you can additionally restrict (vs bias) the result using the `GeocoderComponentRestrictions` as described in the [Geocoding Service docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLbJ6/1/) showing this type of filtering by requiring the results are in the US.

You'll note that the result is in London, USA, but if you remove the `GeocoderComponentRestrictions` from the fiddle code, the first result is now in London, despite the region bias.

However it's still important to note that biasing does work.  For example, if you now change the region to 'ES' and the address to 'Toledo', the result is in Spain.  If you remove the bias, it defaults to Toledo USA.

tl;dr use `region` to bias, and the `GeocoderComponentRestrictions` to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLatLong(address){
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

      geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                return results[0].geometry.location;
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }

       });

  }
     I am unable to understand your exact need but, I hope it will help you and if not then please tell me your exact need in short way
```

Comment: also use in your code : if((ctrysio != '') && (ctrysio != null) && (ctrysio != "undefined")) hope your code also work with this