# Google Geocode region works only in certain cases

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I think this is a bug and I'm going to find out where to submit it to Google but I figured I'd ask here first in case I'm just doing something wrong or misinterpreting something. I cannot get Google's geocoder to consistently use the region bias. For example the following does work:

- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boston` returns Boston, MA
- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boston&region=uk` returns Boston, Lincolnshire in England

However the following does not work

- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=manchester` returns Manchester, UK
- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=manchester&region=us` still returns Manchester, UK

Both Boston, Lincolnshire and Manchester, CT do not appear in the results for the regionless requests so I believe they should work the same. However, it's important to note that it may be dependent on manual region entries. The follow do not work as expected and both return Boston, MA:

- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boston&region=ca` should be Boston, Ontario
- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boston&region=us-ky` should be Boston, KY

## EDIT: JS API

The accepted answer from @dr-molle is correct. However, you're using Google's JS API, you cannot specify `components`. You can specify a bounding region in `bounds` though. To find your bounds you need `LatLng` objects for the NE And SW points of a rectangular box. For CT I did the following:

```
CT_NE_POINT = new google.maps.LatLng(42.05, -71.783333);
CT_SW_POINT = new google.maps.LatLng(40.966667, -73.733333);
CT_BOUNDS = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(CT_SW_POINT, CT_NE_POINT);

...

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({address: 'manchester', bounds: CT_BOUNDS}, someCallbackFunction);
```

## EDIT 2: `componentRestrictions`

The JavaScript API does accept a `componentRestrictions` object. You'll see that [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests) do not show `componentRestrictions` in the object literal but it does describe it below (where it doesn't mention that it is an object). The code in the first edit above can be simplified to:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  address: 'manchester',
  componentRestrictions: { administrativeArea: 'CT' }
}, someCallbackFunction);
```

Comment: Reported as bug here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7419 by me on 12/3/14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Note that biasing only prefers results for a specific domain; if more
>   relevant results exist outside of this domain, they may be included.

To restrict the results to a specific country use [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering)

e.g. [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=manchester&components=country:US`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=manchester&components=country:US)

Comment: Google's docs need to be more explicit. That block you quoted makes me think that additional results _may_ be included in the results but not that they will still be prioritized over your region.

Component Filtering *does* work for the JSON request. I was using that to test when I'm actually geocoding using the JS API. I'll include a separate answer for that.

Thanks for your help!