# Setting Google Maps API v3 Region to Canada

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localization

We are trying to set the region to Canada on our Google Maps component.

From the Google API docs, they have stated to append the region with the key:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&region=GB">`

Tried using this as the src and it does not work:

`<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&region=CA">`

Or

`<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&region=CA&language=en">`

The above would still default to USA.

However, using this:

`<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&region=CA&language=fr">`

does work, but the language is in French.

Is there a way to set the language to English and set the region to Canada?

Comment: Are you trying to localize the region in order to bias geocoding results?

Comment: @lavar yup that's what we're trying to do.  When inputting an address without a city, we'd like to default to Canada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277068/google-geocode-region-works-only-in-certain-cases) and its answer.

I wrote some [sample code](http://jsbin.com/qelujuc/5/edit?html,output) that seems to work.

You have to include `componentRestrictions` in your geocoding request like so:

```
geocoder.geocode({
          'address': 'London',
          'componentRestrictions': {
            'country': 'CA'
          }
        }, ...)
```

Comment: I do believe this is the correct answer. I'm going to incorporate this in our code base to confirm. I didn't realize that biasing prefers results based on the domain. Thank you very much @lavor!